# How to fix missing module in unit-test file?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, unit-testing

So I'm very new with unit test in Swift. In my project I'm using a couple of frameworks installed in my cocoa pods, but when I was about to write some code in my test file, I always get this error. `missing module: Firebase, Eureka, ImageRow`

[image]

I tried to import these modules above the @testable, but somehow it didn't recognize the module. it keeps on saying `module not found`. I've also tried to remove my pods inside the `inherit search paths`, and it still on asking that I need to import these module. Here's my cocoa pod.

```
target 'ProjectRed' do

  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Eureka'
  pod 'ImageRow'
  pod ‘Firebase/Database’
  pod ‘Firebase/Storage’

  # Pods for ProjectRed

  target 'ProjectRedTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'ProjectRedUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add those frameworks to your test target also.

1. Select your test target in the Targets section of your project.
2. Select the Build Phases tab.
3. Add your frameworks to the Link Binary With Libraries section.

(Note: you may need to add a Copy Files phase before Link Binary With Libraries to get them into the right position.)

Answer (score 3):

```
  target 'ProjectRedTests' do
  inherit! :search_paths
  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Eureka'
  pod 'ImageRow'
  pod ‘Firebase/Database’
  pod ‘Firebase/Storage’
```

For me putting those modules in ProjectRedTests worked.